# How to solve: 'Mono version mismatch'

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, mono, visual-studio-2019

Visual studio 2019 keeps telling me that the Mono version isn't right when im trying to pair to my mac.

I am making a mobile application for iOS in Xamarin.Forms for the last 6 weeks. 
This problem didn't show up during this time, but after i updated to the latest version of Visual studio 2019 last week it (like it normally does) asked me to install the latest Mono version.

This became a problem now because the version it wants me to install isn't even released. I am talking about version '6.4.0.208' while the latest version i could find is '6.4.0.198'. Can anyone help me with this problem?

I have tried uninstalling Mono and than installing it again, but this didn't fix my problem.

Comment: The version of Mono on window are not always keep consistent with it on Mac .Especially when new version is released . Mono.iOS on Mac maybe been released in advance .

Comment: So what can i do on my part? Just wait?

Comment: You can focus the release note of the IDE .